# R graphic: Shifting values of different series so that error bars do not overlap

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

Here is a code:

```
set.seed (12)
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame(a=runif(40,0,1),b=c('a','b','c','d','e'),c=c('Hi','Hello'))
ggplot(dat,aes(x=b,y=a,shape=factor(c))) + stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal)
```

The graph it creates has error bars that overlap so that it is hard to distinguish the limits. I've often seen graphs where the different series (given by the factor c) are slightly horizontally shifted so that error bars does not overlap. Is there a way to achieve this with R when using a categorical variable in x ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like `position_dodge()`:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=b,y=a,shape=factor(c))) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal, position=position_dodge(width=0.2))
```

Example plot:

[image]